# About subordinated clauses embedded in other subordinated clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Is it correct to use subordinated clause that is already subordinated clause of other clause?
E.g: if to take sentence "I know a place where I thought we could go" at that inside sentence "where we could go" other sentence "I thought" Is embedded ". Is it acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I know a place where I thought we could go ___ .*

Yes, it's fine, and quite common. Here, the subordinate content clause *we could go* is embedded inside the subordinate relative clause *where I thought we could go*.

The relativised element, "where" functions as complement of *go* in the embedded content clause, as indicated by the gap notation '___'.

We understand that I know a place, and that's the place where we could go.